# what is the procedure to separate the identifier from any program?

Tags: compiler-construction

i want to implement the following .how would i do this in c ?

```
id     ::= letter { letter | digit | _ } | _main
letter ::= a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l |
           m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x |
           y | z |
           A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
           M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X |
           Y | Z
digit  ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  What do you mean by "implement"?

Comment: this looks like some grammar rules, but what do you want to do with it? Restrict users to such input? this question needs more info

Comment: Any reason not to use an existing parser generator like Bison? http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/index.html

Comment: Please explain what you are trying for

Comment: I am going to design a compiler.I just want to separate the identifier from the program.how do i do this?actually i have got this grammar from a site.now what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

That a specification for a lexical analyser, something which takes a sequence of characters and turns them into lexical elements (or tokens).

Writing a lexical analyser is not a task for the faint of heart and, if you're asking this question, you may want to look into lex or flex to assist you :-) If you have to do it yourself in C, you should investigate finite state machines - these will allow you to convert the textual elements into lexical tokens.

What this is most likely saying is that an identifier consists of either a letter followed by a (possibly optional) letter, digit or `_` character or the characters `_main` (or the token `_main`, it's not clear without further information.

---

Another example may be something like:

```
digit     ::= '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
integer   ::= digit+
float     ::= integer '.' integer
```

which defines:

- a `digit` as one of the numeric characters.
- an `integer` as a sequence of one or more digits.
- a `float` as two integers separated by the `.` character.

Comment: I am going to design a compiler.I just want to separate the identifier from the program.how do i do this?actually i have got this grammar from a site.now what should i do?

Comment: @sanjoy, this is something you probably _don't_ want to do in straight C. Lexical analysis and parsing is a pretty complicated field. You'd be going yourself a great favour of you look into using lex/yacc (old-school like me) or flex/bison (more modern, probably more features). These tools provide a much easier way to do the job.

Comment: What you should do, @sanjoy saha, is pick up a book on compiler design and understand it.  What you are doing right now is roughly the equivalent of saying "I have some pig iron and some charcoal.  How do I make a Formula One race car?"